# mongo shell JavaScript equivalent to --sslCAFile

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ssl

I'm using JavaScript to connect to multiple databases at once from the `mongo` shell. However, one of my databases is on Digital Ocean instead of AWS so I have an SSL certificate on my EC2 server.

In general, I use something similar to this to connect and use multiple servers on one file:

```
var iptDb = connect("###.###.###.###:27017/dbname);
iptDb.auth("username", cat("pw"));
```

In order to connect to my Digital Ocean database, I know that I need to add **?ssl=true**, like below, but I don't know where I put the certificate information.

```
var iptDb = connect("###.###.###.###:27017/dbname?ssl=true");
iptDb.auth("username", cat("pw"));
```

> `mongo` uses --sslCAFile in the shell to give the certificate path.
>
> What would be the equivalent if I want to write it in my JavaScript
>   file?

More information on `--sslCAFile` at [MongoDB Configure SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/configure-ssl/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :). Can you add more details on what you mean by connecting using JavaScript .. are you referring to Node.js or a specific client, and what are the applicable version(s)? The official Node.js driver provides support for SSL options: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/connecting/ssl/.

Comment: @flok Stennie has gave You working answer. And this example in link is flexible and easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie . I'm connecting to multiple databases using a combo shell script and regular javascript script (not node, sadly); the code above is what I normally use in the javascript portion. However, I've never had to connect to a db with SSL before and I don't know where to put the certificate. If I can't find the right way to connect with javascript, I'll seek approval to move forward with node.  Many thanks again

Comment: One last comment:

I would use the above to access multiple dbs as follows:

var original = db.key.find({"do":####}); //this is the shell connection I pass in my shell script; it's referred to as just "db" in my javascript
var intoTheIPT = iptDb.bidstream.findOne({_id: #######); //this is the javascript connection made from var iptDB above; it enables me to call both the db noted in the shell connection and as many additional databases as I want in my javascript code; each DB is referred to by it's variableName.collection instead of db.collection.

Answer (score 2):

The `mongo` shell isn't intended to be a full driver replacement; some options (like `--sslCAFile`) can only be provided as command line parameters. As at MongoDB 3.2 there are other limitations of `mongo` shell scripts such as few I/O options (no input methods and limited output methods).

If your requirements are relatively straightforward and you don't want to install a driver, you could perhaps write a shell script (bash/zsh/...) to run multiple invocations of `mongod` with the expected connection parameters.

For any significant scripting I would recommend using one of the [officially supported drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/) which will include full support for SSL options. For example, see the [Node.js driver SSL connection tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/connecting/ssl/).

Comment: Thanks @Stennie . I'll probably use Node. Ty